# Reading Pdf within the App Android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to read PDFs within the app for Android. is there any inbuilt library which supports such a functionality. If yes please post the code.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in PDF reading functionality in Android.

Here are your possibilities:

- Use a third-party library
  There are some free libraries, but most are GPL - so not for use in closed-source apps) 
  If you don't have to keep your app closed source, I'd recommend e.g. this library: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview
- Use Google Docs in a `WebView` like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696415/google-docs-pdf-viewer).
- Handle the pdf to an external app for displaying. Just create an intent and set the data to your pdf path.

Comment: Google Docs doesn't recognize links in the PDF.